# Plotting resampled data in seaborn

Tags: pandas, time-series, seaborn, resampling

I have a pandas dataframe with some financial operations. One of the columns is 'Date'. I resampled the daily data into months.

```
transfers_all.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(transfers_all['Date']), inplace = True)

monthly = transfers_all.resample('M')
```

However when I try to plot this data with Seaborn like so

```
monthly_plot = sns.lineplot(data = monthly,
                      x = 'Date',
                      y = 'Amount'
                      )
```

I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'get'

If I try to plot the entire dataframe, the x axis shows days, but I want to group them into months. Is there a way to either resample from within Seaborn or get Seaborn to work on my resampled data?

running `print (transfers_all.head().to_dict())` gives the following output:

> {'Additional remarks': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): nan}, 'Data faktur': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): nan}, 'Data faktury': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): '-'}, 'Date': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00')}, 'Expense description': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): 'Opłata za zlecenie stałe'}, 'Expenses category (tag)': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): 'ADMIN'}, 'Komu zwrot': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): 'KG'}, 'Kwota (PLN)': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): 3.0}, 'Kwota VAT (PLN)': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): nan}, 'Kwota w walucie oryginalnej': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): nan}, 'Nazwa sprzedawcy': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): '-'}, 'Numer faktury': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): '-'}, 'Opis wydatku': {Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): nan}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need some aggregate function like `sum`, `mean` with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from `DatetimeIndex`:

```
transfers_all['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(transfers_all['Date'])
monthly = transfers_all.resample('M', on='Date').size().reset_index(name='count')

monthly_plot = sns.lineplot(data = monthly,
                      x = 'Date',
                      y = 'count'
                      )
```

Comment: I tried that. With .sum() i get the following error:
> ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Date'

With .count it displays a plot, but the x axis is no longer a time series but some other numbers, probably counted dates

Comment: It's too long to post in a comment so I'll edit the OP

Comment: It works with .sum() but fails on .count(). I'd like to see how the number of monthly transactions changes over time

Comment: >AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

Comment: @kuleje - oops, my typo, need `monthly = transfers_all.resample('M', on='Date').size().reset_index(name='count')`